# Родительный или дательный?

Tags: синтаксис, морфология, падежи

Вопрос из теста.

**А6. Буква И пишется во всех словах ряда**

1) участвовать в дуэл_; вспомнить о геро_

**2)** поражаться его наблюдательсност_; разбираться в драматурги_

3) всесторонн_м образованием; в сыпуч_м грунте

4) быть в расцвет_ сил; находиться в апати_

**5)** разуч_м песню; вытерп_шь боль

Ответы выделены жирным.

Теперь вопрос.

Почему во втором ряду в словосочетании **поражаться его наблюдательсностИ_** пишется **И**, а не **Ю**?

Поразиться кем -чем, кому-чему. Это ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из словаря:

ПОРАЗИТЬСЯ, св. кем-чем, кому-чему. Сильно удивиться, изумиться. **П. чьей-л. красотой.**

Словари, конечно, надо уважать, но  разве мы так говорим: **поразиться её красотой?** В Нацкорпусе вроде бы во всех примерах  существительные в Д.п.: **поразиться наблюдательности.** Поэтому он **не поразился, а был поражен ее красотой.**

(1) Я был поражен его наблюдательностью, (2) я поразился его наблюдательности. В первом случае субъект  испытывает прямое воздействие со стороны объекта (пассивная конструкция), а во втором он испытывает чувство, направленное на объект.

Это разная грамматика, разные падежи.

Answer (score 3):

Вы же сами написали "Поразиться кем-чем, кому-чему". Поразиться известию, поразиться красотой, так что верно "поражаться (чему?)  наблюдательност**И**

Да, здесь  ответ: 2 и 5.

Comment: Да, но ведь возможен и творительный падеж. Так?

Comment: Но тогда был бы Ь:  наблюдательностью